# Is there a reason why i keep getting module problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, module, npm-install, npm-package

So i am recently working with someone on a project (collaborative work) and he's using some React framework while i am using just few, whenever he made any changes and i pull the changes to the repository i will make sure to install whatever react packages he has installed so i will be able to view the page and continue from my own part so lately he used the React player package and i have installed the package yet i keep getting the "Module not found" error message and i have not been able to work from my end since i have been getting this error. What can i do and what could be the cause ?

I have installed the package and also used the npm audit fix yet the problem keep persisting

Comment: Did you check the node version? Also, if you are using global packages, install it in your local project.